# Error opening Hive split because of Index bound error

Tags: hive, amazon-athena, external-tables

I am encountering weird error while querying data for a particular day. My data is being split into 4 partition based on group, year, month and day. While querying data for a particular day I am encountering following error

```
HIVE_CANNOT_OPEN_SPLIT: Error opening Hive split s3://xxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxx/group=xxxxxx/year=xxxx/month=xx/day=xx/part-000xx-xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxx.snappy.parquet (offset=0, length=936927): Index 7 out of bounds for length 3
```

I am doing a very simple query something like

`select field_name1 from xyzzy where group=xyz and year='2020' and month='04' and day='27'`

If I change the dates, year or any other filtering criteria there is no error. What can be issue with this data ?? I don't have much context to carry on my debug part. Any help in this regard will be helpful

Comment: Problem could be the file itself. Can you try to read the file and check the content? Your changing filtering test has probably ruled out IAM and KMS related misconfiguration.